# Electron | Rpm need to have licence in (main package)

Tags: node.js, electron, rpm

I installed the module of Electron Installer Redhat for compile to RPM, I put the code like the github page of this module, but when I put npm run rpm64 the console puts this:

> nerror: el campo License debe estar presente en el paquete: (main package)\n\n"

I don't know why this happens and I search in a lot of pages and I didn't find information for solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a License: directive in the spec file.